# SublimeText 3: Enabling auto quotes pairing in XML?

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Something went wrong with auto quotes pairing in XML files. It was working fine, but I noticed this behavior today (I think it happened when I installed 'Tag' plugin. I disabled it, but it did not fix it.). When I write opening quote for tag attribute it does not match that quote.

But I checked configuration and `auto_match_enabled` is set to true. Also auto match is working in other file types, like `py`. But for some reason it is not in XML

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] showing exactly what is displayed, where the cursor is, and what happens when you try to add a quote.

Comment: do you still have this problem? maybe in your syntax specific settings for XML, there is `"auto_match_enabled": false`?